# WPF Browser Control Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, single-sign-on, winforms-to-web

I need to have a Embedded browser in my WPF application to show web related content. I have decided to go for WPF Browser control, and my fundamental requirement is I should be able to login to home page directly, without asking the user to sign in again in the web application (Single Sign on). I am able to navigate to the page through the `WebBrowser.Navigate()` method, but I am not able to automatically log in. I have tried  `WebBrowser.Navigate(url, null, null, authHdr);` but of no use. It is directing me to login to the web site. I have also checked something that is possible through Awesomium but didn't find any solution as of now. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Anyone here to give me some idea,,

Comment: This is not trivial yet do-able, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619110/1768303) out for details.