# Windows Authentication with system.windows.forms.webbrowser

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, windows-authentication

I have a .net control that inherits from system.windows.forms.webbrowser, it navigates to a url and extracts some data.

The server it navigates to has now changed to use Windows Authentication and now all of the requests fail with a 401 unauthorized.

Is there anyway to tell the system.windows.forms.webbrowser object to use Windows Authentication?

Comment: Look at [implementing IAuthenticate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619110/1768303).

Comment: If you know the username and password, I think you can put them in the URL -- but I would only do this for HTTPS -- https://user:password@website.com -- also if it's just BASIC auth, you can put the username / password into the correct header field in base64 -- (again, only do this if it's HTTPS) -- if you just want it to auto authenticate, maybe switch to using webclient with ".UseDefaultCredentials" set to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebBrowser` control is basically an instance of **Internet Explorer**, so you could try to add the url of your site site to **trusted sites** zone in Internet Explorer configuration "Internet Options".

If this solves your problem you can also think of doing this programmatically (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972345/programmatically-add-trusted-sites-to-internet-explorer) SO question)

Comment: I think this fixed the issue, it is hard to tell as the vendor released a newer version of the control and I do not have the source to it to see what was changed.